# Problema ao listar todas as imagens

Tags: php, mysql

Boas pessoal e o seguinte eu tenho um upload de fotos que está a funcionar bem, só estou a tentar o problema em exibir todas as fotos através do `for`, aparece sempre uma imagem só precisa da vossa para descobrir onde esta o problema.

**Código**

```
// MOSTRA FOTOS DO POST
$result_anexo_post = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts_anexos WHERE post_id = '".$row_posts->id_post."' AND seccao='fotos_posts'");
$num_fotos = mysql_num_rows($result_anexo_post);

for ($i=0;$i<$num_fotos;$i++) {
    $row_anexo_post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_anexo_post);
    $fotos_post = '<img src="../php/timthumb.php?src=gtm/anexos/posts_fotos/'.$row_anexo_post['id_anexo'].'.'.$row_anexo_post['tipo'].'&h=100&w=100&zc=1" alt="">';
}
```

No `HTML` onde deve apresentar as imagens todas está assim que fica dentro de um array que depois e retornado via ajax para listar na página.

```
    <div style="float:left; margin:0px 5px 10px 0px;">'.$fotos_post.'</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está sempre reescrevendo a mesma variavel, inicie ela e vá concatenando ai depois você imprime, segue abaixo um exemplo.

```
// MOSTRA FOTOS DO POST
$result_anexo_post = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts_anexos WHERE post_id = '".$row_posts->id_post."' AND seccao='fotos_posts'");
$num_fotos = mysql_num_rows($result_anexo_post);

$fotos_post = ''; // Inicializo a váriavel
for ($i=0;$i<$num_fotos;$i++) {
    $row_anexo_post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_anexo_post);
    //Faço a concatenação usando o .
    $fotos_post .= '<img src="../php/timthumb.php?src=gtm/anexos/posts_fotos/'.$row_anexo_post['id_anexo'].'.'.$row_anexo_post['tipo'].'&h=100&w=100&zc=1" alt="">';
}
```

> Nota: mysql_query não é mais recomendável ser usado!! Procure pelo PDO.

Sobre o for.., fica mais fácil você usar o while para isso, segue exemplo abaixo:

```
$fotos_post = ''; // Inicializo a váriavel
while ($row_anexo_post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_anexo_post)) {
    //Faço a concatenação usando o .
    $fotos_post .= '<img src="../php/timthumb.php?src=gtm/anexos/posts_fotos/'.$row_anexo_post['id_anexo'].'.'.$row_anexo_post['tipo'].'&h=100&w=100&zc=1" alt="">';
}
```

Depois basta imprimir o conteúdo da variável como vc fez na div.

Comment: É isso mesmo resolveu obrigado pela ajuda afinal era uma coisa simples, `mysql_query` não é mais recomendável ser usado porquê pode me explicar ?

Comment: A comunidade do PHP vai para de dar suporte para ela, nas versões futuras do PHP seu website pode não funcionar mais.

Comment: O termo correto é depreciada.

Comment: já esta marcada então vou ter de pesquisar sobre PDO visto que é o futuro

Comment: Isso mesmo, evoluir faz parte!!! Já que você vai estudar, procure sobre Design Partner no PHP orientação a objetos, e sobre o uso da classe smarty para separar o HTML da sua regra de negócio.

Comment: Mas PDO muda muito a estrutura de programar ? quero saber para estar preparado se vou ter de alterar muita coisa no site ?

Comment: Muda um pouco, mais não é nada complexo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21693/discussion-between-hiago-souza-and-cesar-sousa).